# Why does React Flow reject this approach?

Tags: react-hooks, flowtype, react-context

I'm building a React app with the `Context API` and `React Hooks`.  I'm trying to follow best practices.  To that end I'm using `Flow` and am trying to adhere to its warnings.

I have a situation where once the user logs in, I want to store some data about this user in a `SessionContext` I've built.  Given that there are only 3 pieces of data right now and they're all primitive, I thought it made sense to have just one Reducer Action:

```
export const sessionReducer = (state: SessionState, action: SessionAction) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_SESSION_PROP: {
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.propName]: action.payload
      };
    }

    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}
```

Here are the Action types I created to account for the 3 types of data:

```
export type UserEmailAction = {type: 'UPDATE_SESSION_PROP',
                               propName: 'currentUserEmail',
                               payload: string};

export type UserAccessLevelAction = {type: 'UPDATE_SESSION_PROP',
                                     propName: 'currentUserAccessLevel',
                                     payload: number};

export type CurrentCompanyNameAction = {type: 'UPDATE_SESSION_PROP',
                                        propName: 'currentCompanyName',
                                        payload: string};
```

In my `SessionContext` I combine these 3 Action types as follows, and then define a Dispatch type from that:

```
export type SessionAction = 
  | UserEmailAction
  | UserAccessLevelAction
  | CurrentCompanyNameAction;

type Dispatch = (action: SessionAction) => void;
```

There are 4 warning messages over top of `sessionReducer` in this code:

```
const [state: SessionState, dispatch: Dispatch] = useReducer(sessionReducer, defaultState);
```

The messages are akin to this: "Cannot call `useReducer` with `sessionReducer` bound to `reducer` because  number [1] is incompatible with  string [2] in property `currentCompanyName` of the return value."

Did I define the Action types incorrectly or is Flow just not intelligent enough differentiate the 3 patterns?  By the way, this approach seems to work fine when run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flow isn't intelligent enough. But you can use different approach that flow will understand:

```
type SessionState = {
  currentUserEmail: string,
  currentUserAccessLevel: number,
  currentCompanyName: string,
};

type SessionAction = {
  type: 'UPDATE_SESSION_PROP',
  payload: $Shape<SessionState>,
};

const sessionReducer = (state: SessionState, action: SessionAction) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_SESSION_PROP: {
      return {
        ...state,
        ...action.payload
      };
    }

    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}
```

https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMBK6AmyDG6UcAvnAGZQQhwDkU6AhvjLQNwBQH+EAdqvACqABQAiAQQAqAUQD6AZWnz5ASQDyAOVnDMa4XAC8dERJkKlqzdt3D2XGAE8w6OPPSpUwPvJiMYLowQOODh8ZCgGXhhBDChpEEZgABsALjgBKGBeAHMAGmDQ8Mjo2PF8Qg8AGXQAN3RUuF5kEAAjInyQsIj0KIBhajBGXgcNRhB0NIysvI4STg50AA9IWDhHZ1d3Tz4ymC9eQ0QC9YnjMSk5RWV1LR09Wg64QYckiEYcNIASeQALRmcADxuDz7Hx+dAAPnyc3sThcomAqEGMHwP0OAApmHs+GlgdteLt9gBKQwQuA1CDAHDzHDofBJRgMcmMuC08iMZBJGBg-y4rag3z+eY8fjwDAgvjYPCEYhGdECcF8iW8HnoXJwLH7JX4wl8EkGMlBEKoADuwBRaMxLH2ADoTiSjSFQowMHATBdzNcrHdhGlHU64AwYOEDv6A3AbZGFf5HuGI5HNXwbc9Xu8CgGYRmuAG2RyuX7006gyH0oL0JwsyESLMuCKBHAANrR054gXg9U4RHI1FpBFIvyogC6hzQWFwBCI8v5kvHMo76HZnO5ZaJbCAA

It will reduce overall amount of code also so I don't think it's too bad.

Comment: Thanks for this.  You introduced `$shape`.  I've begun searching for this and can find no reference.  Might you be able to share one?